# instant resume after suspend

Tags: suspend

My htpc ubuntu (15.10) goes to sleep the second time. When I first send him to sleep, he wakes up instantly.

in dmesg i always see acpi error

```
[   50.344387] ACPI Error: [D1F0] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150619/psargs-359)
[   50.344390] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L09] (Node ffff8802180b8758), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150619/psparse-536)
[   50.344392] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L09] (20150619/evgpe-592)
```

dmesg: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13752448/

Help me please.